# Python module setup.py dependency updates by Renovate combined with GitLab Package Registry

Tags: python, gitlab, setup.py, renovate

We have Python modules, which were referencing other Python modules from an internal GitLab Package Registry. The `setup.py` looks like the following:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="dummy-module",
    version="0.1.0",
    author="Dummy User",
    author_email="dummy.user@local.com",
    description="Dumm module.",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[
        "other-internal-module @ https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/projects/1/packages/pypi/files/0635d9dc9b32911047c19d2814b0b574be7c91756de2283f5217d9e098f79bab/other-internal-module-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl",
        "python-ldap==3.4.4"]
)
```

Our goal is to not use a separate `requirements.txt` with redundant content and also to install all dependencies directly when installing the Python module `dummy-module`. This works so far by using the `setup.py` with `install_requires`, as shown above.

Renovate is configured and also able to detect and update `python-ldap` inside the `setup.py`. However, the `other-internal-module` will not be updated. Might it's because of the "direct reference" (-> `@ https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/projects/1/packages/pypi/files/0635d9dc9b32911047c19d2814b0b574be7c91756de2283f5217d9e098f79bab/other-internal-module-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`) or Renovate is not able to handle this kind of references.

[image]

So my question would be:

- Does anyone have a hint, how it would be possible to get dependency updates by Renovate for `other-internal-module` in this kind of construct?
- Or might another idea of how to define internal hosted (by GitLab Package Registry) Python modules inside the `setup.py` that during module `dummy-module` installation the module `other-internal-module` will also be installed from the local GitLab Package Registry?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/26308), Renovate is at the moment not able to handle these kinds of dependency.

```
"other-internal-module @ https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/projects/1/packages/pypi/files/0635d9dc9b32911047c19d2814b0b574be7c91756de2283f5217d9e098f79bab/other-internal-module-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl"
```